# Including a subclass item in a superclass method in python

Tags: python, class, import, subclass

I want to have something like the following:

```
class superclass:
    def __init__(self):
        "blahblah"

    def some_method(self):
        variable = subclass() #This is a subclass of this superclass
        "do stuff with variable"
```

Edit2: I have the two classes defined in separate files.  This is the issue I am running into:

- When I import the superclass into the subclass file, it is unable to import superclass because superclass can't be defined without subclass being defined too, and if I try to import subclass into the superclass file it is unable to do so because subclass cannot be defined without superclass being defined.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Edit3:  The reason I need this subclass in the method instead of a superclass instance is because when one of these instances is defined it is assigned an empty slot in an array of size 256.  The subclasses can be deleted to free up one of these slots and later on a different subclass can take that same slot - However, objects of the superclass cannot take slots that have previously been taken by a subclass.

Overall, it is set up like this:

1. There are two boolian arrays AvailableSlots, and AvailableSlots2 of size 256, each initially with every index set to True.
2. When a superclass is defined it looks through to find the first True index in AvailableSlots2 and then sets AvailableSlots[index] to False and AvailableSlots2[index] to False.
3. When a subclass is defined it looks through to find the first True index in AvailableSlots and then sets AvailableSlots[index] to False and AvailableSlots2[index] to False.
4. When a subclass is destroyed it sets only AvailableSlots[index] to True, leaving AbailableSlots2[index] set to False.  This makes it so that the next time I define a subclass, it takes this slot, but if I define a superclass it skips this slot.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me: what are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Agree. As a sidenote: are you sure you want to hardcode the exact type of the subclass?

Comment: I want to have a subclass which is deletable while instances of the superclass itself are not.  Additionally, instances of the subclass must be initialized in a slightly different way.

Comment: @Keagan Can you [edit] your question to ask that instead: Try to include a [mcve].

Comment: why not defined the subclass outside the superclass and then you can do variable = subclass()? you agree?

Comment: @ TemporalWolf  Well, that's not really my question though.  The subclasses, since they are deletable, are defined in a different way from non-deletable instances.  I need specifically instances which are defined in that way in the methods of the superclass, so there is no way (as far as I know) around figuring out how to do what I asked in the OP question.

Comment: @repzero I tried that, but I can't define the subclass after the superclass, nor before it.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @Keagan. It is possible...I believe you may be doing something wrong somewhere..can you put in your code how you are defining that subclass and at which position in your codes you are doing so?

Comment: @repzero, Oh so it is.  the issue I am running into then is from the fact I have the class and subclass defined in different files and cannot import one before the other.

Comment: What do you mean by "deletable"? You need to provide a *complete* example that shows why you need to reference the subclass from the superclass.

Comment: When you run into issues like this, it is often a sign that what you want to do isn't a good "fit" for a class hierarchy. Keep in mind that Python is more than just an object-oriented language.

Comment: @chepner I really don't think it would be too helpful, but I will add it.

Comment: @chepner it is edited in now.